# Multiple pair with makeSceneTransitionAnimation not working on Android N

Tags: android, android-animation, android-7.0-nougat

I am doing some Activity transitions, and everything work fine in Android 6. Since I updated my phone to Android 7 the animation does not work anymore.

So here my two activities: 
[little sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJONT.png)

There are two animations :

- The green background go from all the screen to just on the top.
- The red circle go from center to an other position in the top bar (in my application it is an ImageView)

I use this block of code to create my animation on my first sreen

```
redCircle.setTransitionName(getString(R.string.transition_red_circle));
greenBackground.setTransitionName(getString(R.string.transition_green_background));
Pair<View, String> p1 = Pair.create(redCircle, redCircle.getTransitionName());
Pair<View, String> p2 = Pair.create(greenBackground,   greenBackground.getTransitionName());
ActivityOptionsCompat options =    ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(SplashActivity.this, p1, p2);
...
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

And this one on my second one to link my elements:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    redCircleSecondScreen.setTransitionName(getString(R.string.transition_red_circle));
    greenBackgroundSecondScreen.setTransitionName(getString(R.string.transition_green_background));
    ...
}
```

Do someone see anything wrong ?